# finding a column header, copying the data, and pasting values in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a range of data from one worksheet "A" to another "B"  the code I have is copying cells is copying some data from "A" and pasting it in "A".... i'm not sure what the issue is...

```
    Sub findazuredataandcopyit()

Dim WBB As Excel.Workbook
Dim WBA As Excel.Workbook
Dim Ed As Excel.Worksheet


Set WBB = Workbooks("Source.xlsx")
Set WBA = Workbooks("MODEL.xlsb")


Dim Col As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim Rngm As Range
Dim RngSku As Range
Dim RngPO As Range
If Application.CountIf(WBB.Sheets("B").Rows(1), "plan_tamaward*") > 0 Then
    Col = Application.Match("plan_tamaward*", WBB.Sheets("B").Rows(1), 0)
    LastRow = WBB.Sheets("B").Cells.Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlByRows).Row
    Set Rngm = Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(LastRow, Col))
Else
    MsgBox "The column named like plan_tamaward* was not found in Row1.", vbExclamation, "Column Not Found!"
    Exit Sub
End If

'set range for sku

If Application.CountIf(WBB.Sheets("B").Rows(1), "plan_sku_*") > 0 Then
    Col = Application.Match("plan_sku_*", WBB.Sheets("B").Rows(1), 0)
    LastRow = WBB.Sheets("B").Cells.Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlByRows).Row
    Set RngSku = Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(LastRow, Col))

Else
    MsgBox "The column named like plan_sku* was not found in Row1.", vbExclamation, "Column Not Found!"
    Exit Sub
End If

' set range for PO

If Application.CountIf(WBB.Sheets("B").Rows(1), "plan_sku_*") > 0 Then
    Col = Application.Match("Rack PO #*", WBB.Sheets("B").Rows(1), 0)
    LastRow = WBB.Sheets("B").Cells.Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlByRows).Row
    Set RngPO = Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(LastRow, Col))
    'do whatever you want to do with this range here
Else
    MsgBox "The column named like Rack PO #* was not found in Row1.", vbExclamation, "Column Not Found!"
    Exit Sub
End If

     MsgBox "the range is" & Rngm.Address
      MsgBox "the range is" & RngSku.Address
       MsgBox "the range is" & RngPO.Address

    WBA.Sheets("Sourcesheet").Range("F4").Resize(Rngm.Rows.Count).Value = Rngm.Value
    WBA.Sheets("Sourcesheet").Range("E4").Resize(RngSku.Rows.Count, 1).Value = RngSku.Value
    WBA.Sheets("Sourcesheet").Range("C4").Resize(RngPO.Rows.Count).Value = RngPO.Value

MsgBox "the range is" & Rngm.Address
      MsgBox "the range is" & RngSku.Address
       MsgBox "the range is" & RngPO.Address
End Sub
```

The code seems to run perfectly (finding the correct columns, assigning the variables, and displaying the correct range)  the problem seems to lie in these three lines:

`WBA.Sheets("Sourcesheet").Range("C4").Resize(RngPO.Rows.Count).Value = RngPO.Value`

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not qualifying which worksheet you are referring to in your statements such as

```
Set Rngm = Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(LastRow, Col))
```

Those statements will therefore set the range to be something on the ActiveSheet.

You should fully qualify your `Range` and `Cells`:

```
Set Rngm = WBB.Sheets("B").Range(WBB.Sheets("B").Cells(2, Col), WBB.Sheets("B").Cells(LastRow, Col))
```

---

Your code after rewriting could end up looking something like:

```
Sub findazuredataandcopyit()

    Dim WBB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim WBA As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Ed As Excel.Worksheet

    Set WBB = Workbooks("Source.xlsx")
    Set WBA = Workbooks("MODEL.xlsb")

    Dim Col As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim Rngm As Range
    Dim RngSku As Range
    Dim RngPO As Range

    'Use a With block to save typing 'WBB.Worksheets("B").' over and over
    With WBB.Worksheets("B")
        'Set LastRow once - no need to do it each time a range needs to be set
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

        If Application.CountIf(.Rows(1), "plan_tamaward*") > 0 Then
            Col = Application.Match("plan_tamaward*", .Rows(1), 0)
            'Fully qualify `Range` and `Cell` (etc) objects
            Set Rngm = .Range(.Cells(2, Col), .Cells(LastRow, Col))
        Else
            MsgBox "The column named like plan_tamaward* was not found in Row1.", vbExclamation, "Column Not Found!"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'set range for sku
        If Application.CountIf(.Rows(1), "plan_sku_*") > 0 Then
            Col = Application.Match("plan_sku_*", .Rows(1), 0)
            Set RngSku = .Range(.Cells(2, Col), .Cells(LastRow, Col))
        Else
            MsgBox "The column named like plan_sku* was not found in Row1.", vbExclamation, "Column Not Found!"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' set range for PO
        'If Application.CountIf(.Rows(1), "plan_sku_*") > 0 Then ' <-- this seems wrong
        If Application.CountIf(.Rows(1), "Rack PO #*") > 0 Then  ' <-- maybe this?
            Col = Application.Match("Rack PO #*", .Rows(1), 0)
            Set RngPO = .Range(.Cells(2, Col), .Cells(LastRow, Col))
        Else
            MsgBox "The column named like Rack PO #* was not found in Row1.", vbExclamation, "Column Not Found!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    MsgBox "the range is" & Rngm.Address
    MsgBox "the range is" & RngSku.Address
    MsgBox "the range is" & RngPO.Address

    'Use a With block to save typing 'WBA.Worksheets("Sourcesheet").' 3 times
    With WBA.Worksheets("Sourcesheet")
        .Range("F4").Resize(Rngm.Rows.Count, 1).Value = Rngm.Value
        .Range("E4").Resize(RngSku.Rows.Count, 1).Value = RngSku.Value
        .Range("C4").Resize(RngPO.Rows.Count, 1).Value = RngPO.Value
    End With

    MsgBox "the range is" & Rngm.Address
    MsgBox "the range is" & RngSku.Address
    MsgBox "the range is" & RngPO.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe a `With` clause is appropriate here ;)

Comment: @A.S.H - LOL - yes, but then sometimes people think that the `With` is the actual solution to the problem rather than realising that the fully-qualified ranges (which are made easier by the `With`) are the solution **and** I would have had to have rewritten several lines of code (because the `With` should be placed around several lines before this one) **and** I was about to go out to do the Saturday morning shopping ... so I decided to be lazy and leave it out.  (But now I am home again, I might edit the answer to include a more extensive version of the code.)

Comment: haha you are right. I only wanted to notify the OP about this tool if (s)he ever feels the task of qualifying all in this kind of statements a little tedious (which is often the case).

Comment: Aaaah... This makes sense.  I never understood why people use the `with` clause.  that clears up so much!  Thank you for taking the time to help teach me the concept, instead of giving me the solution.   slowly, i'm learning.

Comment: @VBArookie - be careful - if you learn too much you will need a new userid! :D